# Why has debug dll a dependence on a certain dll but release does not

Tags: visual-studio, dll, build, lib, jsoncpp

This seems to be a tricky question, also because it is difficult to present here all settings involved. So let me state the total picture:

I use Visual Studio 2022 to build a solution (all in x64 mode) comprising of two projects

CapopConsole

and

CapopWrap

CapopConsole is a C# Console-Project generating an exe and CapopWrap is a C++/CLI project wrapping a C++ native library called Capop. It generates a dll called CapopWrap.dll. CapopConsole has CapopWrap as dependency.

CapopWrap has three extra .lib dependencies, namely

capoplib.lib, libpredicates.lib, jsoncpp.lib

in Release mode and

capoplib.lib, libpredicates_d.lib, jsoncppd.lib

in Debug mode.

The first two of each row are from a certain project, special for me, the last one is from the well known jsoncpp project. All three libs are built with Visual Studio 2022 with the new CMake mode (no 'solutions').

Now the point is: Compiling and linking CapopWrap produces both for release and debug mode respectively a result dll, in both cases called CapopWrap.dll.

But: *CapopWrap.dll from debug mode has a dependency on jsoncppd.dll whereas CapopWrap.dll from release mode has no explicit jsoncpp related dependency whatsoever* (as shown with dumpbin, for example).

By symmetry one might expect that CapopWrap.dll (Release) would incur a dependency on jsoncpp.dll but this is not the case.

I would really be happy, if someone could help me find an explanation for this - my own attempts so far where fruitless.

Addendum: I do not give concrete excerpts from my .csproj and cmake files at first, because they are a bit lengthy and maybe an answer is possible without them. If not, please tell me, what you want to see concretely from my configuration files (or filesystem contents), I will edit it in then.

Comment: Is it possible that the calls you make to functions in "jsoncpp.lib" are inlined by the linker in the release build?

Comment: @Adrian Mole I will look through the capoplib code (where the calls are made) for this possibility. In fact there are uses of jsoncpp which will probably not be inlined, but maybe these are not called from the portion of the code I actually use. Maybe there is a linker/compiler option to prevent inlining in Release mode and then see, if a dependency on jsoncpp.dll appears?